# Amend node value in existing XML document and print result with DOM PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I am looking for the best method to replace a node value using DOM in PHP.

An example XML would be, which is stored as *data.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I have been following https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp, which works great to print out the XML file without any edits using the following code:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("data.xml");


print $xmlDoc->saveXML();
?>
```

Now I'm not sure how to go about editing the values of, for example, change *Jani* to *Smith* and print the new changed xmlDoc.

Comment: There is some notes on replacing a node value [in this doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php), but I wonder if this is easier in SimpleXML!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$from = $xpath->query('/note//from')[0];
$from->nodeValue="John";
echo $xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>John</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```